# In R, how do I show superscripts on the legend using a variable that has a number saved inside of it?

Tags: r, plot

I have this variable `pVal`, which is like `pVal <- 6.4234e-04 (or some number)`

I want the `legend()` of a `plot()` to show `6.4234^-4`. Without of course, the `^` symbol.

I've tried:

```
legend("topright", c("P value:", as.expression(bquote(pval))))

legend("topright", c("P value:", expression(pVal)))

legend("topright", c("P value:", bquote(pVal)))
```

Comment: `6.4234^-4` is not the same as `6.4234e-04`. Do you want to display `6.4234 \cdot 10^{-4}` (in LaTeX notation)?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `sfsmisc` has a function `pretty10exp` that generates scientific notation with superscript.

```
library(sfsmisc)
pVal <- 6.4234e-04
plot(0)
legend("topleft", pretty10exp(pVal), bty="n")
```

[image]

Comment: What do the different lines mean? I don't know what to exclude and what to include.

Comment: I just need the superscript on the Legend, so what does the title and eaxis (axis?) have to do with it

Comment: I added a figure that shows what the code does. You can add text before the P-value if needed.